# Script that works in the browser console but not when in the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a very simple piece of javascript code that just should work and it only works when I run it in the browser console:

```
<script>
    $(".hopscotch-close").click(function () {
        alert("Hi");
        Cookies.set("tourState", "closed")
    })
</script>
```

Because it runs in the console I know that:
1) the `".hopscotch-close"` is OK;
2) there are no errors in the code that could prevent it from running;

Also:
1) because is a "click" event I know that I haven't got a problem with the DOM being ready (and I can put everywhere - but in this case in at the bottom of the `<body>`;
2) I know I don't have an issue because of using the same name for a class than something else that exist;
3) The behavior is the same in Safari and Firefox, so its not a Browser issue.

I know this is tough without the full code, but if someone has experienced this maybe has na idea about what could be the problem.

Comment: `.hopscotch-close` element gets appended dynamically?

Comment: check `$(".hopscotch-close").length` before binding the click handler, if it is 0, you know that you do not have the needed element

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, it is and I think you're right...(please see comment below)

Comment: @drys You're absolutely right! It is 0. So I wrapped my code inside a `setTimeout` to check and then it is 1! IS there and alternative to setTimeout if the Hopscotch library doesn't allow me to wrap this in a callback?

Comment: @drys I'm going to accept GuruprasadRao answer but I'm going to follow you so that I can up vote your anwsers because you deserved huge merit here. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments I sense that the `element` is getting appended `dynamically` so instead of

```
$(".hopscotch-close").on('click',
```

you need to make use of **[`event-delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** as

```
$(document).on('click','.hopscotch-close',function(){
```

That will do the trick.

> If you are appending `.hopscotch-close` to any already existing static
>   `element` then instead of `$(document).on('click'` you can use
>   `$('#yourStaticElementId').on('click','.hopscotch-close',function(){`
>   which improves site performance.